# usepackage hyperref error

Tags: hyperref

I'm writing my thesis with LaTeX. When I add the `hyperref` package, I face with this error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
```

This is my preamble and document structure:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, headsepline, numbers=noenddot, bibliography=totoc, listof=totoc, parskip=half, footinclude=false, DIV12, BCOR=5mm, cleardoublepage=empty]{scrbook}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}     
\usepackage{graphicx}           
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{afterpage} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{snakes,arrows}
\usepackage[cuteinductors,american,smartlabels,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subfigure}         
\usepackage{booktabs}           
\usepackage{longtable}           
\usepackage{amsmath}            
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc} 
%\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % I add this
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{IRT_SaDa}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\usepackage{titlesec}
```

I will be really thankful if someone tell me what should I do here?

Comment: Did you try loading hyperref as the `last` package?

Comment: I have tried that, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. the package IRT_SaDa is not part of the full texlive installed and removing it from the preamble makes the code compile.